# Mongoose using populate with an array of id's

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to use `populate` in order to get just the documents with the id's specified in an array?

For example, this is how it works right now

```
Collection.findOne({element: elementId})
.populate({
  path: references
})
.exec((err, run) => {
  ....
});
```

And I'm searching for something like:

```
Collection.findOne({element: elementId})
.populate({
  path: {references: {_id: ["5ae9b6ac268d162b15747340", "5ae9b6ac268d162b15747341"]}}
})
.exec((err, run) => {
  ....
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$in` and `match` in populate query

```
Collection.findOne({element: elementId})
.populate({
  path: 'references',
  match: {
    _id: {
      $in: ["5ae9b6ac268d162b15747340", "5ae9b6ac268d162b15747341"]
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to first declare it in your mongoose schema so it knows where to populate the data from. Please refer to : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html